# Bash Scripting - How to direct output to multiple inputs in OpenVPN?

Tags: bash, shell-script, openvpn

So i'm trying to write a script to ease the process of connecting to OpenVPN server.

So when i write:

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn
```

It prompts me to type username and password:

```
Wed Apr  1 21:23:28 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] 
[EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Wed Apr  1 21:23:28 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username:            
Enter Auth Password:
```

Here i want my script to automatically send username and password to OpenVPN.

I had the following attempts:

Attempt 1:

```
{ echo "vpnbook"; echo "3vze4vd"; } | openvpn --config vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn
```

Attempt 2:

```
echo -e "vpnbook\n3vze4vd" | openvpn --config vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn
```

Attempt 3:

```
(echo $username; echo $password;) | openvpn --config vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn
```

But none of them are working, i'm getting the following output:

```
Wed Apr  1 21:38:14 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Wed Apr  1 21:38:14 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10
```

Then nothing happens.

Can someone please give me a hint on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to add the username and password to a secure file (one that only the owner can read). Look up the `auth-user-pass` pass in your OpenVPN documentation for details (`man openvpn`):

```
cat > /path/to/secret <<'X'
myusername
verysecret
X
chmod u=rw,go= /path/to/secret
```

Now find the `auth-user-pass` directive in your OpenVPN configuration file and extend it like this

```
auth-user-pass /path/to/secret
```

Comment: Thank you very much
This exactly solve my problem, but in a better manner than what i was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

For the purposes of this demonstration, I wrote a short script to impersonate the behavior of your openvpn command:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo "Wed Apr  1 21:23:28 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4]"
echo "[EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019"
echo "Wed Apr  1 21:23:28 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10"
read -r -p 'Enter Auth Username: ' USERNAME
read -rs -p 'Enter Auth Password: ' PASSWORD

echo
echo "username was $USERNAME"
echo "password was $PASSWORD"
```

Here's a short expect script that responds to these prompts:

```
#! /usr/bin/env expect

spawn ./fakevpn --config vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn

expect "Enter Auth Username: " { send Hello\r } # \r is the "return" character.
expect "Enter Auth Password: " { send World\r } # It simulates hitting the Enter key.
expect eof # This ensures expect won't exit until there's no more output.
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```bsh
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/vpn]$ ./vpn_expect
spawn ./fakevpn --config vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn
Wed Apr  1 21:23:28 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4]
[EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Wed Apr  1 21:23:28 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username: Hello
Enter Auth Password:
username was Hello
password was World
```

Edit: roiama's solution is superior to this one for security reasons. I'll leave this up in case it's helpful for someone trying to figure out how to automate interactive commands.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time and effort to answer my question
I've gone with roiama's answer for this scenario (since OpenVPN has a built-in capability of reading credentials through files)
Thank you again